# how to write this type of inner join

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have following table `tbl_info`

```
  ---------------------------------------
  |  id   |  parentid  |  sortsequence  |
  |--------------------------------------
  | 1     |   0        |        1       | 
  |--------------------------------------
  | 2     |   1        |        1       | 
  |--------------------------------------
  | 3     |   1        |        1       | 
  |--------------------------------------
  | 4     |   1        |        2       |
  |--------------------------------------
  | 5     |   0        |        1       | 
  |--------------------------------------
  | 6     |   5        |        1       | 
  |-------------------------------------|
  | 7     |   5        |        2       |
```

**My Problem**

I need to find out ids of those records and their children ids (where id of some record exists as parentid) whose child's `sortsequence` column is not unique. For Example If `id 1` has children `2,3,4` then sortsequence for `2,3,4` must be unique. If they are not unique, they are faulty records and I need to find out such records.

**updated after comments**

Parent child relationship is made from `id` and `parentid` fields. If `id` of some record exists as `parentid` of other records then these other records are children of those records. **Now I need to find out those records where `parentid` is same but sortsequence is not unique.**  The ideal condition and correct condition is that all records where parentid is same then sortsequence must be unqiue. In above case records `2,3,4` are faulty records. I need to find out these records

**What I have done so far**

I have searched a lot and written this query

```
SELECT id, parentid, tbl_info.sortsequence FROM tbl_info
   INNER JOIN (SELECT sortsequence FROM tbl_info
GROUP BY sortsequence HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup ON tbl_info.sortsequence = dup.sortsequence
```

This query first finds all records whose sortsequence is the same but I need to find out with respect to `parentid`. Second I have million of records in this table so I need a query with minimal processing time.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand the problem description.  Using your example above, what are the results you wish to return?

Comment: How do you know the parent child relationships? Could you post the structure of that table?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/702fc/13/0

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd16d/1 @eqqyal Thanks dude. But now there is one more column language. I want if language is different then dont put this check

Comment: 6,7 are also faulty records ?

Comment: @Meherzad no they are not. They have unique sortsequence with same parentid

Answer (score 0):

what about simply joining the two tables on the condition that are faulty.. if having the same parent you can't have the same sortsequence...

```
SELECT child.id AS [thischild]
, child.sortsequence AS [isinthespot]
, sibling.id AS [allongwiththissibling]
FROM tbl_info child
INNER JOIN tbl_info sibling ON child.parentid = sibling.parentid --sameparent
AND child.sortsequence = sibling.sortsequence --and in sameplace
WHERE child.parentid > 0 --remove roots
AND child.id < sibling.id --remove duplicate return (because 2 is in same spot as 5 AND 5 is in the same spot as 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

similarly if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_info WHERE parentid in (
SELECT parentid FROM tbl_info
GROUP BY parentid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sortsequence) <> COUNT(sortsequence)
)
```

Comment: this gives you all the parentids right? So you could use this as a subquery. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
     distinct b.id 
FROM 
     tbl b, 
     (select 
          t1.parentid AS rId
          FROM 
             tbl t1
          group by 
             t1.parentid
          HAVING 
             count(t1.parentid) <> count(distinct t1.sortsequence)
     ) a
WHERE 
     a.rId = b.id  or
     a.rId = b.parentId;
```

The inner query list's the parentId which dont have the unique sort sequence and its result is used to list parent and child of that id.

Hope this helps

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080ae/6)